# Calling a Stored Procedure dynamically using Groovy SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, groovy

I've a grails application service where I'm trying to call a stored procedure dynamically.

Here is a sample snipper of what I'm trying to do:

```
myService.callProcedure (procedureName, inputParams)
```

My stored procedure takes input and out params. How I can call a procedure on the fly without registering output parameters and then get all the output parameters as a ResultSet or something.

e.g:
`def results = sql.firstRow("call $procedureName(?, ?, ?, ? .....)", inputParams)`
where I would expect 'results' to have all out parameters returned by the procedure.

Is it possible?

Thanks,
Alam Sher

Answer (score -1):

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Database+features

Scroll Down to the Stored Procedure Support